# Heroku: PHP Fatal error for valid function - mb_check_encoding

Tags: php, heroku

I have the following statement:

```
$img->setTitle(mb_check_encoding($item['title'], 'UTF-8') ? $item['title'] : utf8_encode($item['title']));
```

This works on my local setup of PHP 5.4.17 and my shared host which has PHP 5.3.xx

But when I deploy this app to Heroku (which has PHP 5.3.10), it gives the following error in the logs:

`2012-12-26T09:55:28+00:00 app[web.1]: [Wed Dec 26 09:55:27 2012] [error] [client 10.119.79.71] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_check_encoding() in /app/www/includes/utils.php on line 44, referer: https://imagemash.herokuapp.com/`

As per the [php.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php), `mb_check_encoding` *is* supported for PHP 5 >= 5.1.3.

What am I doing wrong? Or is my app somehow using an older version of PHP? There does not seem any php.ini value that needs to be set to enable this function as well..

Comment: You need to [install the `mbstring` extension](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php).

Comment: Did you check that your host's PHP includes the multibyte string extesnion?

Comment: @DCoder I don't think I can install extensions in a heroku environment. I'll check on that. If there are standard alternatives to this function (to ensure I have utf-8 encoded strings) please give that as an answer... Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to DCoder's pointer and the tutorial at http://chrismcleod.me/2011/11/30/use-custom-php-extensions-on-heroku/, installed the mbstring.so extension available at https://github.com/wuputah/heroku-libraries

This solved the problem

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to AJ.

```
$ yum install php-mbstring
```

And perhaps reload the apache:

```
$ systemctl reload apache2
```

Comment: For anyone having a similar error and using apt: `apt-get install php-mbstring` and `systemctl reload apache2` will solve it

Answer (score 4):

Add `composer.json` to your project root with content:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-mbstring": "*"
    }
}
```

More info https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on Red Hat Linux.

You need to install the mbstring extension. Here is a link to the installation:

http://www.knowledgebase-script.com/kb/article/how-to-enable-mbstring-in-php-46.html

This solved the issue for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are a linux user then just run

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

Here just maintain your php version, i.e **php7.2-mbstring** or **php7.3-mbstring**

And don't forget to restart your server, to restart just run run:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```